# How to display self-joined fields in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, self-join

I'm trying to build a comment section to a social-media-esque web app I'm building. I have a datatable storing comments using Django, and would like to build in a reply feature. Here is my model:

```
class Comments(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    replyto = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author + ' commented: ' + self.text
```

Essentially, whenever someone replies to a previous comment, I'd store that previous comment's ID in the "replyto" field, with which I'd like to link the current comment to that previous comment. In getting the current comment from the view I set up, I'd like to get all fields of the current comment (as outlined above) as well as the text and author of the previous comment (i.e. comment being replied to).

In base SQL, I'd figured this would be a bit of self join logic. How do I do this in Django (and show the additional text and author fields of the being-replied-to comment as described above)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

heres my solution, its not efficent but im not sure how else to do it

```
class Comment(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # answer = models.ForeignKey(Answers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author + ' commented: ' + self.text

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Comment, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.child_comments_list = []

    @classmethod
    def update_all_child_comments_lists(cls):
        all_comments = cls.objects.all()
        for comment1 in all_comments:
            for comment2 in all_comments:
                if comment1.id == comment2.parent_id:
                    comment1.child_comments_list.append(comment2)
        return all_comments
```

so the returned `all_comments` from `update_all_child_comments_lists` will return every comment with the an attribute `child_comments_list` that contains a list of all its child comments